# Breaking string occurrence dynamically in SQL based on data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the below data in a table. Now I need to separate the string based on the "-" value. The separation needs to be done based on the below output scenarios.

| Name | Required Output |
| --- | --- |
| itim-connect-prd | CONNECT |
| WHATS-PRD | WHATS |
| Commitment-FinOps | COMMITMENT |
| itim-xbl-hml | XBL |
| itim-audit-hml | AUDIT |
| BSC-AWS-Accounts-Roots | AWS |

For example, in the above table, the [Name] column is the source data and I need to convert the [Name] column to the [Required Output] column.

To get the above required output column, I have used the below SQL Script... But it didn't work for the scenarios like **Commitment-FinOps&WHATS-PRD** values.

SQL script used

```
UPPER(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([Name],CHARINDEX('-',[Name])+1,CHARINDEX('-', [Name], CHARINDEX('-', [Name]) + 1)),1,CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING([Name],CHARINDEX('-',[Name])+1,CHARINDEX('-', [Name], CHARINDEX('-', [Name]) + 1)))-1)) AS Required Output
```

Can anyone modify the script so it will work for all scenarios.

Comment: What is the desired output for an input such as `Commitment-FinOps&WHATS-PRD`?`Commitment`?

Comment: WHATS and COMMITMENT... For Example in the above table [Name] column is the source data and I need to convert the [Name] column to [Required Output] column.

Comment: Please update your question to clarify that. Is that 2 separate rows? Or what?

Comment: And your query doesn't actually work - it gives a length error.

Comment: And you seem to ignore 'itim' and 'BSC'... but don't explain the logic behind it

Comment: You don't actually *explain* what the logic is here; just give us sample data and expected results and expect of to work it out. Is the TL;DR: Always the second value, unless there are only 2 values, and then the first?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want the first substring if there are two parts and second one if there are more. You can use a bunch of `charindex`:

```
select *
from (values
    ('itim-connect-prd'),
    ('WHATS-PRD'),
    ('Commitment-FinOps'),
    ('itim-xbl-hml'),
    ('itim-audit-hml'),
    ('BSC-AWS-Accounts-Roots')
) as t(name)
cross apply (
  select nullif(charindex('-', name), 0)
) as ca1(pos1)
cross apply (
  select nullif(charindex('-', name, pos1 + 1), 0)
) as ca2(pos2)
cross apply (
    select case
      when pos2 is null then substring(name, 1, pos1 - 1)
      else substring(name, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1)
    end
) as ca3(result)
```

In SQL Server 2022 you can use `string_split`.

Comment: OP wanted `UPPER` :)

Comment: That would be the easy part :)

Comment: Exactly... so you might as well add it to avoid a question about it later

Comment: And you should add `Commitment-FinOps&WHATS-PRD` to your values

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution based on *tokenization*.

It is using SQL Server's XML and XQuery functionality.

Notable points:

- 1st `CROSS APPLY` is converting tokens column into XML.
- 2nd `CROSS APPLY` is counting number of tokens in the XML.
- XPath predicate `/root/r[1]` or `/root/r[2]` is retrieving needed token.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(256));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('itim-connect-prd'),
('WHATS-PRD'),
('Commitment-FinOps'),
('itim-xbl-hml'),
('itim-audit-hml'),
('BSC-AWS-Accounts-Roots'),
('Commitment-FinOps&WHATS-PRD');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '-';

SELECT *
    , result = UPPER(IIF(cnt=2
        , c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)')
        , c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)')))
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.value('count(/root/r)', 'INT')) AS t2(cnt);
```

**Output**

| id | tokens | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | itim-connect-prd | CONNECT |
| 2 | WHATS-PRD | WHATS |
| 3 | Commitment-FinOps | COMMITMENT |
| 4 | itim-xbl-hml | XBL |
| 5 | itim-audit-hml | AUDIT |
| 6 | BSC-AWS-Accounts-Roots | AWS |
| 7 | Commitment-FinOps&WHATS-PRD | FINOPS&WHATS |